# Search in iOS for custom objects

Tags: ios, ios7, range, nspredicate

I am working on a custom contact,currently i'm using  this code to search custom objects

```
    filteredTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<contactSectionTitles.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *sectionTitle = [contactSectionTitles objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *sectionmContacts = [mContacts objectForKey:sectionTitle];
        for (CS_ContactDTO *theDto in sectionmContacts) {
            NSRange nameRange = [theDto.mFirstName rangeOfString:text options:NSForcedOrderingSearch];
            NSRange descriptionRange = [[theDto.mFirstName description] rangeOfString:text options:NSForcedOrderingSearch];
            if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound || descriptionRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                if (![filteredTableData containsObject:theDto])//Search DTO
                {
                    [filteredTableData addObject:theDto];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note**
"theDTO" is my custom class
It has values FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber.

The code gives me result like, 

For "A" -> "Arun","India","Kumar"

My requirement is like to search 
"A" should provide only "Arun"(starting letter matching),not the other results.

Comment: Didn't understand your requirement, Do you want to search for `name` or `description` that starts with search string?

Comment: i need to search for first name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change your check to see if the range location is 0:

```
if (nameRange.location == 0 || descriptionRange.location == 0) {
```

This will be true if `text` is at the start of the name or description.

BTW - why do you check both `mFirstName` and `mFirstName description`? What's the difference?

Comment: i was taking a chance (hit n trial) to get the desired result.

Comment: You should never rely on the output of the `description` method. It should only be used for debugging.

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy ,it worked,can you please explain what does description do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if `NSString` starts with a particular `search` term, you can use

```
if ([myString hasPrefix:@"searchTerm"])
```

Comment: This works well for simple cases. Using `rangeOfString:options:` offers more options such as case and diacritic insensitive matches.

Comment: @rmaddy, yes I agree, because the OP just wants to check if string begins with a search term I proposed this method.